# jquery input mask plugin add/remove based on first three digits

Tags: jquery, plugins, input-mask

I am using the [jQuery inputmask plugin](https://robinherbots.github.io/Inputmask/#/documentation), version: `5.0.9-beta.4`.
I have a username field that should only be masked if first 3 characters entered by the user is equal to `784`, else the mask should be removed.

```
var inputMsk = $('#txtUsername').inputmask('999-9999-9999999-9');
inputMsk.inputmask('remove');
$('#txtUsername').on('input', function() {
    var fieldValue = $(this).val();
    if (fieldValue.startsWith('784')) {
        if ($('#txtUsername').inputmask) {
            inputMsk = $('#txtUsername').inputmask('999-9999-9999999-9');
        }
    } else {
        if ($('#txtUsername').inputmask) {
            inputMsk.inputmask('remove');
        }
    }
});
```

The above code generates an error in the console when I a enter `784` and then remove the `4`.
The error is:

> Uncaught TypeError: f is not a function

The console identifies the following code from the `inputmask.js` plugin file as the source of the error:

```
keypressEvent: function (e, t, i, a, o) {
  var c = this.inputmask || this,
  u = c.opts,
  f = c.dependencyLib,
  p = c.maskset,
  d = c.el,
  h = f(d),//----------on this line error is generated
  m = e.key;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have much previous experience with the [inputmask plugin](https://robinherbots.github.io/Inputmask/#/documentation), but I worked on your code example and I arrived at a solution that seems to work.

First, the Type Error is being thrown by the plugin's code. I don't know exactly what is causing it, but it looks to me to have something to do with the timing of when the mask is removed and the handlers for the `keyup` event are fired. This gave me a hunch that wrapping the `.inputmask('remove')` call in a `setTimeout` with a timeout value of `0` could help - and it did. For more information on this, see: [Why is setTimeout(fn, 0) sometimes useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/779379/3397771).

The `setTimeout` prevented the error, but it did not clear the mask. So I tried re-setting the mask with an empty string, `.inputmask('')`, instead of calling `.inputmask('remove')`. This seems to have given the desired effect.

```js
const $input = $('#txtUsername');

$input.on('input', function() {
  const fieldValue = $input.val();
  
  if (fieldValue.startsWith('784')) {
    $input.inputmask('999-9999-9999999-9');
  } else {
    setTimeout(() => {
      $input.inputmask('');
    }, 0);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/inputmask@5.0.8/dist/jquery.inputmask.min.js"></script>
<input id="txtUsername">
```